# What is a "new member" in Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

I have joined a Google Group in which "Messages from new members are moderated". What determines a new member? Join date? Post count?

Answer (score 1):

http://groups.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47792 says only:

> Check the box next to "Messages from new members are moderated," and you'll be able to review messages from the members who've recently joined your group before they're posted.

No indication of what "recently joined" means.